# zxing.net barcode decode without resize

Tags: c#, barcode, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to decode Multiple QR Code with zxing.net and DecodeMultiple method but by default it return null collection result.
When I resize my picture and then decode most of QR code was decoded successfully but one or two small QR Code not decode.
Here is my Pictures:
[image]
[image]

and here is my code:

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
reader.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
reader.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
reader.AutoRotate = false;
reader.TryHarder = false;
Bitmap input = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\1.jpg");
Resize_Picture(Application.StartupPath + "\\1.jpg", Application.StartupPath + "\\1_resized.jpg", 800, 0, 100);
var results = reader.DecodeMultiple((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\2.jpg"));
```

Why this picture required resize?? what is the best size for QR Code. Please guide me to decode without image resize.
thanks

**After Edit (I add QR Code for test):**

I upload my QR Cod you can download from [here](http://www.up2www.com/uploads/1389184488391.rar).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the default binarizer has some trouble with the background color and the anti-aliasing arround the QR codes. You should use the GlobalHistogramBinarizer.

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader(null,
    bitmap => new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap),
    luminance => new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(luminance));
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but your solution not working. I update question and add my .jpg files.

Comment: The JPG files are using the colorspace CMYK which actually isn't supported by the BitmapLuminanceSource. Please convert it to RGB before. Otherwise only the option TryInverted = true will give any results. But that option doesn't work correctly with the QRCodeMultiReader class. That is fixed in rev. 87947. Hopefully I can add CMYK support in the next version of the library.

Comment: Thank you is working now :)